# Gitlab CI: is it possible to access artifacts from previous jobs that stores them in the same path?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How do Gitlab CI behaves, if there are 2 jobs that have artifacts in the same path, and both jobs are the dependency of the same job?

```
job1:
 stage: stage1
 artifacts:
  paths: 
  - samedir
  
job2:
 stage: stage1
 artifacts:
  paths: 
  - samedir

job3:
 stage: stage2
 dependencies:
 - job1
 - job2
```

I couldn't find the example in gitlab docs or the expected behaviour.

Is the behaviour deterministic? If the job1 and job2 puts the same file in the samedir, will the job2's artifact overwrite that from job1 because of the order they are defined in the dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#the-latest-job-artifacts)

> Job artifacts created in the most recent successful pipeline for a specific ref are considered the latest artifacts. If you run two types of pipelines for the same ref, timing determines which artifacts are the latest.

to prove this statement let's consider the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```yaml
image: python:3.6

stages: 
    - stage1
    - stage2
    - stage3


job1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - echo "artifact from stage 1" > test.txt
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - test.txt

  
job2:
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - echo "artifact from stage 2" > test.txt
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - test.txt

job3:
  stage: stage3
  script:
    - cat test.txt
  dependencies:
    - job1
    - job2
```

We notice that both `job1` and `job2` give the same reference for the file `test.txt`.

Now, if I run both jobs at the same time, **the most recent succesful job will store the latest artifact** to be available at `job3`. In this example, `job1` took 87 seconds while `job2` took 90 seconds. The output from `job3` confirm this

[image]

On the UI `CI/CD --> Pipelines` you're still able to download each job artifact

[image]

Comment: So if I need artifacts from both jobs, I must write them to the separate directories, otherwise I'll get a race condition?

Comment: exactly, @9ilsdx9rvj0lo on your case is there any limitation to write to different directories?

Comment: No, in some cases it could be better. I was just thinking about storing the 'output' of maven build of multiple projects, without pushing them to central or shared storage, but it's probably not the best idea ever.

Comment: What if the artifacts used different names like `artifacts:name`. Maybe that still won't work as they will be unpacked to the same location.